# How to properly create long text labels inside ScrollView in Kivy?

Tags: android, python, ios, kivy

I've tried to create MWE to demonstrate my problem, and I only ended up being more confuse about this.

I want to create an app with several widget. One of the widgets will hold long text that I expect will span over about 3 line. I want the label holding this text to increase its height to adjust to the text size.

This is what I got so far

```
    layout = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
    subLayout = TwoLabelCombo()
    subLayout.label1.text = ('foo:')
    subLayout.label2.text = 'bar'*50
    subLayout.label2.width = int(Window.width*0.8)
    subLayout.label2.text_size = [subLayout.label2.width,None]
    subLayout.label2.size_hint_y = None
    subLayout.label2.height = subLayout.label2.texture_size[1]
    subLayout.height = subLayout.label2.texture_size[1]
    layout.height = subLayout.height
```

`TwoLabelCombo` is a `BoxLayout` with orientation set to horizontal that holds to labels with `size_hint_x` set to 0.2 and 0.8. `layout` holds an entire line in the app with similar layouts about and below it. The text does span over several line, but the layout does not update with the text and thus, the overlap with other widget. printing the `texture_size` I learn that it's height is 0. How do I get the proper text size?

Answer (score 1):

So there are two issues here. First, the issue of sizing the `Label` to its content.

You're on the right track with assigning the `height` based on `texture_size`. But the problem is that when you first create the `Label`, the texture has not been rendered yet so you can't know the size. The key is to use [property bindings](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html#observe-properties-changes) instead - then the `height` will **update** every time `texture_size` changes.

So, in [the kv language](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html) (the preferred way to define UI in Kivy):

```
Label:
    text: 'some really really really long text here'
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.texture_size[1]
    text_size: self.width, None
```

Properties are automatically bound when they are referenced in kv. But you could do this similarly in Python:

```
lbl = Label(text='some really really really long text here',
            size_hint_y=None)
lbl.bind(texture_size=lambda instance, value: setattr(instance, 'height', value[1]))
lbl.bind(width=lambda instance, value: setattr(instance, 'text_size', (value, None)))
```

Second, there is the issue of the containing `BoxLayout`. Even with setting these `Label`s to the right sizes, the `BoxLayout`s they are inside of will still be layed out normally. Here's a drop-in replacement for `BoxLayout` which will resize itself based on the size of its children (when `size_hint` is set appropriately):

```
class CollapsingBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CollapsingBoxLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._trigger_update_size = Clock.create_trigger(self._update_size)

    def on_children(self, *_):
        for c in self.children:
            c.bind(size=self._trigger_update_size)
        self._update_size()

    def _update_size(self, *_):
        if self.size_hint_y is None:
            self.height = max(c.height for c in self.children) if self.children else 0
        if self.size_hint_x is None:
            self.width = max(c.width for c in self.children) if self.children else 0
```

And, finally, a full working example:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.8.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class CollapsingBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CollapsingBoxLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._trigger_update_size = Clock.create_trigger(self._update_size)

    def on_children(self, *_):
        for c in self.children:
            c.bind(size=self._trigger_update_size)
        self._trigger_update_size()

    def _update_size(self, *_):
        if self.size_hint_y is None:
            self.height = max(c.height for c in self.children) if self.children else 0
        if self.size_hint_x is None:
            self.width = max(c.width for c in self.children) if self.children else 0

root = Builder.load_string('''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    CollapsingBoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None

        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 0, 0, 0.2
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

        Label:
            text: 'Paragraph 1'
            size_hint_x: 0.2
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            text_size: self.width, None
        Label:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0, 1, 0, 0.2
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            size_hint_x: 0.8
            text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sollicitudin dignissim orci. Pellentesque laoreet magna quis augue dictum fringilla. Vivamus nec adipiscing nunc. Aliquam pharetra auctor justo vel rutrum. Sed sodales nulla sed odio fermentum, vel pulvinar nibh hendrerit. Phasellus a volutpat leo. Donec id hendrerit velit. Curabitur eget suscipit neque, nec tincidunt nulla. Donec feugiat, urna quis porttitor aliquet, nibh est laoreet ligula, vitae vestibulum leo purus quis ante. Maecenas magna nisi, molestie eu ipsum quis, tempor tempor turpis. Vivamus a fringilla enim. Quisque aliquam elit tortor, nec mollis tellus facilisis accumsan. Phasellus sagittis commodo mauris in vestibulum. Mauris sed ultrices enim.'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            text_size: self.width, None

    CollapsingBoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None

        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 0, 1, 0.2
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

        Label:
            text: 'Paragraph 2'
            size_hint_x: 0.2
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            text_size: self.width, None
        Label:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0, 1, 0, 0.2
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            size_hint_x: 0.8
            text: 'Duis egestas dui lobortis ante rutrum, nec consectetur arcu sollicitudin. Phasellus ut felis facilisis, eleifend odio malesuada, placerat odio. Etiam convallis non mi at tempor. Nunc gravida est magna, a hendrerit nulla condimentum a. Proin tristique velit quis dui convallis, vitae sodales nunc condimentum. In sollicitudin eros augue, sit amet blandit neque accumsan eu. Mauris non risus at nisl vestibulum dignissim quis non arcu. Integer ullamcorper felis eu neque viverra placerat. Vivamus magna quam, porta ac tincidunt a, imperdiet sed purus. Phasellus tempus ac neque vel accumsan. Pellentesque ligula justo, auctor eget aliquet ultricies, volutpat scelerisque ligula. Maecenas dictum velit id neque rhoncus fermentum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur dictum enim nisl, ut elementum lectus viverra sit amet. Praesent vel tempor risus, at congue turpis. Praesent in justo lobortis, gravida lacus id, facilisis orci.'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            text_size: self.width, None
''')

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        lbl = Label(text=('hello this is some long long text! ' * 10), size_hint_y=None)
        lbl.bind(texture_size=lambda instance, value: setattr(instance, 'height', value[1]))
        lbl.bind(width=lambda instance, value: setattr(instance, 'text_size', (value, None)))
        root.add_widget(lbl)
        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. At first, I used the kivy language, but I found it quite confusing, and most examples/documentation I've found where in python code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that `texture_size` isn't updated until the texture is actually generated and displayed, which may not have happened by the end of your method (but probably does before the next frame). For this reason, you generally want to bind to properties, not take their instantaneous values.

Your whole rule can be expressed more simply, and with this additional functionality for free, in kv language (I'm making some guesses about the widget addition that you didn't include in the post, but you should see the general idea).

:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: label2.texture_size[1]
    Label:   # label1
        text: 'foo:'
    Label:   # label2
        id: label2
        text: 'bar' * 50
        width: int(Window.width*0.8)  # This might be better done via a layout
        text_size: self.width, None

I've also changed things slightly, setting the root BoxLayout's height rather than that of the label, I think this will work better.

Of course you can also do this in python, by recreating the relevant bindings with the bind method of widget (this is what kv does behind the scenes), but it's more verbose.

I have a video that covers some of this, amongs other things, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdcUg_rX2fM).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anybody else is searching for a solution to a self expanding ScrollView which contains a BoxLayout or GridLayout which for reference is really the widget that is self expanding. With Ryan P 's answer I got most of the way there; but then I realized that he was addressing a very specific use case and that is why he is using the max function. 
What I needed was a box that expanded as new widgets were added. so I simply modified his code for _update_size() to be:

```
def _update_size(self, *_):
    temp_height = 0
    if self.size_hint_y is None:
        for c in self.children:
            temp_height += c.height
        self.height = temp_height + 10  # Add a buffer to the bottom to prevent text clipping.
    if self.size_hint_x is None:
        self.width = max(c.width for c in self.children) if self.children else 0
```

A few caveats I left the width portion alone because it made sense to act this way for my use case but it could be modified in a similiar way.

Also the simplest way to change the size of a Label widget using this method is to delete the widget using remove_widget() then create a new widget using kivy.lang.Builder.load_string() and add that widget to your self expanding/collapsing BoxLayout or GridLayout, it will recalculate it's size and that will adjust the scroll view's scrolling distance appropriately. Don't forget that size_hint_y: None it must equal none or no updates will be applied.

Hopefully that is enough detail to help any one through the edge cases.